# GAE loading slow in localhost

Tags: localhost, google-app-engine

I am using Google App Engine with Python to learn HTML/Python/Web-development, and since the GAE 1.8.8 update loading an app in localhost is extremely slow, taking up to 60 seconds. Static files still work as fast as they used to.
I am not getting any error messages, I've tried completely un- and re-installing GAE and python, as well as returning to GAE 1.8.7 or using the IPv6 address, with no change.
The problem always occurs when calling a .py app, even if this is just a "Hello World" one, while static files load nearly instantly. And it's not the Browser, I've tried Chrome/IE/FF, all three of them say they spend 30-60 seconds "waiting" after having sent the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the problem: it was zone alarm blocking me, had to uninstall it, deactivating only wasn't enough